# Eu não consigo executar o código pois o PyCharm diz que a classe App não foi criada

Tags: python, python-3.x

O PyCharm diz que a classe App não foi definida, só que isso não faz o menor sentido já que que eu criei a classe App.

```
from tkinter import *
class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        Label(frame,text='Graus C').grid(row=0)
        self.c_var = DoubleVar()
        Entry(frame, textvariable=self.c_var).grid(row=0,column=1)
        Label(frame,text='Graus F').grid(row=1)
        self.result_var = DoubleVar()
        Label(frame,textvariable=self.result_var).grid(row=1,column=1)
        button = Button(frame,text='Convert',command=self.convert).grid(row=2,columnspan=2)

    def convert(self):
        print('No implemented')

root = Tk()
root.wm_title('Conversor de graus C para graus F')
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 52, in run_file
>     pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
>   File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.1.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>     exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
>   File "C:/Users/nicol/PycharmProjects/Projetos/converter.py", line 2, in <module>
>     class App:
>   File "C:/Users/nicol/PycharmProjects/Projetos/converter.py", line 19, in App
>     app = App(root)
> NameError: name 'App' is not defined
> ```

Comment: Qual é a mensagem de erro? E tem como verificar a indentação do seu código? Pois na pergunta está errada, mas não é possível dizer se ficou errada apenas quando colou o código na pergunta ou se está errada originalmente.

Comment: eu já arrumei na pergunta, mas no código a identação está correta. A mensagem de erro eu coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: Troca o nome da classe para outro, instaloou o modulo pelo control s certinho?